# Selecting a value from a python data frame if a condition is met

Tags: python, if-statement, dataframe

My data frame looks as follows:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv("SKU12345.csv", index_col=0)
```

where the CSV I refer to has the following values:

```
  SKU,Tag,Fall,Wert  
 0,12345,1,WE,1000
 1,12345,1,ABV,10
 2,12345,1,PRO,0
 3,23456,2,WE,10000
```

I want to make an if-condition which reads as follows:

```
If 'Fall' == 'WE' 
and if 'Wert' of this row > 100:
print('Wert' of row with 'Fall' == 'WE')
```

The outcome I wish to get is

```
1000
10000
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
for v in df[(df['Wert'] > 100) & (df['Fall'] == 'WE')]['Wert'].values:
    print(v)
```

Essentially, you first filter the DataFrame by all values bigger than 100 in column `Wert`, and by column `Fall` for `WE`

```
df[(df['Wert'] > 100) & (df['Fall'] == 'WE')]
```

The `&` is required to chain several conditionals - it cannot be replaced by `and` or `&&` afaik.

and then directly access the values within the column `Wert`.

```
df[(df['Wert'] > 100) & (df['Fall'] == 'WE')]['Wert'].values
```

`.values` of a column returns the column's data as a `numpy.array`, so you can just loop over it like a list.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that. True, this is not included, but can be altered. One second, I'll update my answer

Comment: you saved me after 4 hours of researching ;)

Comment: Cheers, no problem - if you work with `pandas` more often, you should give Wes KcKinney's book on Data Analysis a read. It explains the library quite well and is a great reference.